# Use 'Boolean' variable in domain class, table not created

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want use a boolean attribute in a domain class in Grails with a MySQL database. However when I run this application, this table is not created and there aren't any error messages. But when I remove this attribute `read`, this table is created successfully.

Domain class:

```
class Message {

    Player author
    Player target
    String content
    boolean read

    static constraints = {
        target nullable: false
        author nullable: false
        content blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        read defaultValue: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are facing this issue because `read` is reserved keyword [according to MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R):

```
READ(R)
```

You can change variable name `read` to something else or you can use `mapping` closure to change column name to something else, for instance:

```
class Message {

    Player author
    Player target
    String content
    boolean read

    static constraints = {
        target nullable: false
        author nullable: false
        content blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        read defaultValue: false, column: 'is_read'
    }
}
```